# Is the $l_2$ norm squared strongly convex?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

There's a theorem that states that  if $f$ is continuously twice-differentiable and $\nabla^2f(x) \succeq mI$ for all $x$ (with $m>0$), then $f$ is strongly convex.

If $f$ is the $l_2$ norm squared of some vector is $f$ strongly convex? I know $f$ is continuously twice-differentiable but I can not prove the second part of the theorem.

Answer (score 1):

We say that a function $f:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is strongly convex if
$$f(y) \ge f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y-x) + \frac{\mu}{2}\|y-x\|^2_2$$
for all $x,y \in \Bbb R^n$, for some $\mu > 0$.

In our case, we have $f(x) = \|x\|^2_2$. Then, $\nabla f(x) = 2x$, so that $\nabla f(x)^T (y-x) = 2x\cdot y - 2x\cdot x$. Clearly, $\mu = 2$ does the trick.

For details, see that
$$\begin{align*}
f(y) - f(x) - \nabla f(x)^T(y-x) - \|y-x\|^2_2 = y\cdot y + x\cdot x - 2x\cdot y - (y\cdot y + x\cdot x - 2x\cdot y) = 0 \ge 0
\end{align*}$$

Therefore, $f$ is strongly convex.